# Undefined variable data when I try to import a csv file in php

Tags: php, sql

Im trying to import a CSV file in my SQL Database using PHP.

I have this code

```
<?php  

    echo $_FILES['userfile']['name'];

    echo $_FILES['userfile']['size'];

    include ("AccesoBD.php");

    if ($_FILES['userfile']['size'] > 0) {
        echo "El archivo contiene informacion";

        $file = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']; 
        $handle = fopen($file,"r"); 
        $data2 = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",","'");

        do { 
        if ($data[0]) { 
            echo "Entramos en el Import";
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO Alumno (Nombre, Apellidos, CorreoElectronico) VALUES 
                ( 
                    '".addslashes($data[0])."', 
                    '".addslashes($data[1])."', 
                    '".addslashes($data[2])."' 
                ) 
            "); 
        } 
        } while ($data = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",","'")); 


    }


?>
```

I get the file information correctly, and AccesoBD it´s an extra class to manage my conexion to the database, but I get the error that data variable is not declared.

The point is that the loop enters the correct number of times as it should do and prints the correct number of times the echo "Entramos en el Import", but then inserts nothing to find no such variable data.

The literal error that gives me the browser is

```
alumnos.csv80El archivo contiene informacion
Notice: Undefined variable: data in C:\xampp\htdocs\iprofesor\importaralumnoss.php on line 17
Entramos en el ImportEntramos en el Import
```

PD Sorry if i have a bad english, it´s my first time trying to make a formal question using the language :)

Comment: please highlight your code

Comment: user3462511, How can i do that ?

Answer (score 0):

You defined $data2 and then use $data which is undefined.

```
$data2 = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",","'");

    do { 
    if ($data[0]) {
```

Comment: data is defined at the end of the do while, I only defined data2 to make othe failed try

Answer (score 0):

you have not defined $data try

```
$data2 = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",","'");

        do { 
        if ($data2[0]) { 
            echo "Entramos en el Import";
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO Alumno (Nombre, Apellidos, CorreoElectronico) VALUES 
                ( 
                    '".addslashes($data2[0])."', 
                    '".addslashes($data2[1])."', 
                    '".addslashes($data2[2])."' 
                ) 
            "); 
        } 
        } while ($data2);
```

Comment: is your previous condition is ok while($data2 = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",","'"))

Comment: Yes, I could solve that defining it before the do while. In addition, i have find the problem in the SQL query, I have added the mysql_error() at the end of the INSERT block and I found that I wasn´t inserting correctly

Comment: you need to choose an helpful answer so OP can use

Answer (score 0):

`do .. while` first executes the contents of the `do` block, *then* the `while` expression. On the first run `$data` does not exist, because it's only set in the `while` expression after the first execution. You actually want a regular `while`:

```
while ($data = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",","'")) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Yes, I could solve that defining it before the do while.

In addition, i have find the problem in the SQL query, I have added the mysql_error() at the end of the INSERT block and I found that I wasn´t inserting correctly.